# Loop through all classes and Ids of selected element and its childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know, how it is possible to loop through all classes and Id's of an element and all its children. For example:

```
<elem id="wrapper">
  <elem class="first"></elem>
  <elem id="second">
     <elem id="sub"></elem>
  </elem>
</elem>
```

and I just want to output:

```
#wrapper, .first, #second, #sub
```

as a `console.log` or similar. **Note:** I always want to select the highest parent `$('#wrapper');` and loop through all siblings and nested siblings.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Have you read about jquery's `find` method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all elements by passing `*` into [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method. Something what you need might look like:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').find('*').each(function (i, elem) {
        $elem = $(elem);
        console.log($elem.attr('id') ? '#' + $elem.attr('id') : '.' + $elem.attr('class') );
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyygxarv/2/)